# How to refer to <% in asp.net

Tags: terminology, asp.net

I've realized that I refer to `<%@` as 'angle bracket percent at' and `<%$` as 'angle bracket percent dollar',

But this is very clumsy. I think `<%$` should be referred to as some sort of bind, I'm not 100% sure what `<%@` does, and Google doesn't like that as a search term.

How do programmers normal label these terms?

Comment: If you need to dig further, [angle bracket percent](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=angle+bracket+percent) seems to work just fine as a search term.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a site for learning. Could the downvoter please direct me to an appropriate site for this question then, if this is the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, Colin. I also learnt some Google search tips. I should have thought of using that as a search term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<%@` is called a directive block.  This is documented here: [Directives for ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8syafc7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

`<%$` is called an ASP.NET Expression. This is documented here: [ASP.NET Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)

The official generic term for these is [Code Render Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  They are colloquially know as [Bee Stings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997124/bee-stings-vs-webcontrols) or [Code Nuggets](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).